# C++ implemented interface calling wrong virtual overloaded method

Tags: c++, interface, shared-libraries, unreal-engine4

I have a problem in which a function call during executing is calling a completely wrong implemented interface function that is overloaded. I call a function passing a bool parameter and the implemeted function actually being called is the one with a float paramater...

Here's my use case, may be a little bit confusing:

- I'm writing a game in which a user will write arduino code in a Unreal Engine (UE) widget that will be saved into a .cpp file.
- Behind the curtains, usercode.cpp (saved file) will get the user written code and "inject" some useful stuff, making a small code look like this:

```
#include "IArduino.h"

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void setup();
    __declspec(dllexport) void loop();
    __declspec(dllexport) void InitArduinoPtrs(IArduino*);
};


IArduino* arduinoPtr = nullptr;

void InitArduinoPtrs(IArduino* InArduinoPtr)
{
    arduinoPtr = InArduinoPtr;
}

void setup()
{
    arduinoPtr->pinMode(true);
}
```

**Injected code: "IArduino.h", "extern C stuff", "arduinoPtr" and "InitArduinoPtrs()"

- I have a interface called "IArduino" that has a function defined as virtual that is overloaded (test only):

```
class IArduino
{
public:
    virtual void pinMode(float) = 0;
    virtual void pinMode(bool) = 0;
};
```

- I'm compiling this usercode.cpp as a shared library (usercode.cpp using IArduino.h):

  g++ -c -I[IArduino.h_PATH] -Wall -fpic ./usercode.cpp -o ./usercode.o 2>&1

  g++ -shared -o ./usercode.so ./usercode.o 2>&1
- On my Unreal Engine project, I created a "ArduinoImpl[.h,.cpp]" that implements "IArduino" interface:

```
class ARDUCOMPILATIONTEST_API ArduinoImpl : public IArduino
{
public:
    void pinMode(bool portNumBoolTest);
    void pinMode(float portNumTest);
};
```

- At runtime in Unreal Engine, I'm using GetProcAddress() to get setup() and InitArduinoPtrs() functions.
- With linked InitArduinoPtrs(), I call it passing the pointer to a new object of "ArduinoImpl()" (that implements IArduino.h):

**At another class that runs in runtime:**

```
 m_setup_function = (m_setup)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(m_dllHandle, TEXT("setup"));
 m_init_function = (m_init)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(m_dllHandle, TEXT("InitArduinoPtrs"));

 ArduinoImpl* arduinoImplPtr = new ArduinoImpl();
 if (m_init_function)
     m_init_function(arduinoImplPtr);

 if (m_setup_function)
     m_setup_function();
```

My problem is, usercode.cpp setup() is run, then:
When the "arduinoPtr->pinMode(true)" is called, it's calling "ArduinoImpl::pinMode(float)" instead of "ArduinoImpl::pinMode(bool)", completely messing up the overloaded call. Moreover, if I try to write "arduinoPtr->pinMode(2.5f)", it calls the bool overload instead of float overload... The same thing happens if I try with different parameters, such as int, string, etc.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

- I tried logging the results, such as logging the float I receive when "arduinoPtr->pinMode(true)" is called and I get garbage value (such as 0.5, 512.803, 524288.187500, ...). Trying to log the "bool" value when "arduinoPtr->pinMode(2.5f)" is called, I get "208".
- I tried forcing a cast on call like "arduinoPtr->pinMode(static_cast(true))" and it still calls the float param overloaded function.
- I tried with different params type and the same thing keeps hapenning.

Comment: Mark the member functions in your `Impl` class as `override`.

Comment: It seems that you mean to export `setup` as a C language function.But a C language function may not support overloading and overriding.

Comment: May you have several (conflicting) declarations of `class IArduino` (with order of methods reversed)?

Comment: @bitmask tried that, no go :(

Comment: @YZ_SO that's a good point, but I'm not interested in setup() func. pinMode() is the one with problems, and it's not exported

Comment: @Jarod42 I only have a single definition of class IArduino... but got me thinking. In usercode.cpp I do use "#Include IArduino.h", but I also include it on "ArduinoImpl.h"... maybe Unreal's Build Tool is messing up something

Comment: @SauloSoaresOliveira Do you have the option to compile and run with ASAN and UBSAN? I suspect you have maybe a buffer overrun somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Is the unreal engine project (that loads your shared library) compiled with the same compiler and the same compiler flags as your shared library? I mean, something along the lines that maybe the vtable layout expected by the unreal engine project is different to the one in your shared library, like for example exchanged vtable entries? Just a wild guess...

Comment: Also, something that I find confusing: You have `__declspec(dllexport)` in your code, which is only used on Windows (MSVC, mingw). Similar for `GetProcAddress()`. On the other hand, you produce the shared library as a .so file, which is only used on Linux but not on Windows. Is your .so file actually a .dll file?